# json_encode function return Braces {} when array is empty in php

Tags: php, json, xml

I am using json_encode to convert the array to json. But json is giving braces {} if value is blank for some key . I want the value should come null or "" blank. Please help .Below is the code :

```
<?php
$postData='<Lead>
<General>
<dealer></dealer></General> </Lead>';
 $array_data = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($postData));
$array_data=json_decode($array_data) ;
$dealer=$array_data->General->dealer;
$data=array('dealer'=>$dealer);
echo  $objectJson =json_encode($data);
?>


response is : {"dealer":{}}
```

Comment: Try checking your contents before encoding it.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong place, `simplexml_load_string` generates empty objects so `json_encode()` correctly encodes them to `{}`: https://eval.in/710579

Answer (score 2):

It's because your `$dealer` is an empty array which in json is same as `{}`

Use ternary

```
'dealer'=>((!$dealer) ? $dealer : null)
```

this means that if `$dealer` is empty assign a null which will change your empty array or `{}` in json to a `null`

```
$data=array('dealer'=>((!$dealer) ? $dealer : null));
```

also

```
echo  $objectJson =json_encode($data);
```

if you just display it and not use it again in code below avoid declaring it  instead just display it

```
echo json_encode($data);
```